# checking if a function with no return executed properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have simple function that aims to log a user in via localstorage,
and then a second one that checks if the user can be found ( i need it separated because i need the logincheck elsewhere)

```
  logInUser(user: IPerson): Boolean {
    localStorage.setItem(this.userID, JSON.stringify(user));
    return this.isUserLoggedIn();
  }

 isUserLoggedIn(): Boolean {
    return Boolean(localStorage.getItem(this.userID));
  }
```

But this code seems bad to me because im not actually verifying that logInUser did its job, im just calling another function for this.
I was thinking about converting this into a Promise of boolean and chain .then() but this doesnt work with setItem()

technically, setting something to a storage does not return anything, so i dont know how to verify correctly that it did and catch errors.

Answer (score 0):

If it returns without exception you can assume it worked. If you really want you can double check it with `localStorage.getItem(this.userID) === JSON.stringify(user)` and that's the ultimate test.

Exception might occur if you try for example to `setItem` in a snippet in stack overflow.